# Why i get a straight line from my neural network model, but the actual distribution should be a curve?

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to fit a data set similar to gauss distribution with a simple neural network, but the effect is not good. The fitting result is always straight and no matter how I adjust the learning rate or increase the epoch, it has no effect.

[blue is the data points and red is model's output at same X value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWbly.png)

I also try to use the same model to fit other functions, and the result is that other curves can be fitted well.

So I don't know whether there are problems in my training process or data or the model is too simple.

here's my code

```
class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden1, n_hidden2, n_output):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden1 = torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden1)   
        self.hidden2 = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden1, n_hidden2)
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden2, n_output)  

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.hidden1(x))      
        x = F.relu(self.hidden2(x))
        x = self.predict(x)             
        return x

net = Net(n_feature=1, n_hidden1=200,n_hidden2=100, n_output=1) 

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.00005)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()

train_x = torch.tensor(X.reshape(-1,1),dtype=torch.float32)
train_y = torch.tensor(Y.reshape(-1,1),dtype=torch.float32)

for t in range(5000):
    prediction = net(train_x)   

    loss = loss_func(prediction, train_y)   

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()   
    optimizer.step()  

    if t % 5 == 0:
        print("Epoch{}, loss:{:.6f}".format(t, loss.data.numpy()))
```

After hundreds of epochs of training, the loss value will be fixed to a relatively large value and will not decrease any more. No matter I turn up the learning rate, the loss value will not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why the network doesn't train**

The primary issue is that your data are not remotely normalized (x ranges from ~3500 to ~6500 and f(x) from 0 to ~25000).

Neural network framework default configurations (the weight initialization and optimizer settings provided by PyTorch / TensorFlow / etc.) are generally set assuming inputs and outputs with a range of around [-1, 1] ([0, 1] works fine, [-2, 2] works fine, but [3500, 6500] will work poorly).

**How to fix training**

If you rescale your inputs / outputs to be in a range around [-1, 1], your neural network should be much happier.

Example code (I also adjusted the optimizer settings a bit to make it converge faster):

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden1, n_hidden2, n_output):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden1 = torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden1)
        self.hidden2 = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden1, n_hidden2)
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden2, n_output)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.hidden1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.hidden2(x))
        x = self.predict(x)
        return x


net = Net(n_feature=1, n_hidden1=200, n_hidden2=100, n_output=1)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.0003)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()

losses = []

for t in range(500):
    # distribution similar to original data
    train_x = torch.empty(128, 1).uniform_(3500, 6500)
    train_y = (0.01 * (train_x - 5000)) ** 4 + 5 * (
        train_x - 5000
    ).abs() * torch.randn_like(train_x)

    # vvvv this part is important! vvvv
    rescale_data_to_suitable_range = True
    if rescale_data_to_suitable_range:
        train_x = (train_x - 5000) / 1500
        train_y = train_y / 50000
    prediction = net(train_x)

    loss = loss_func(prediction, train_y)

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    losses.append(loss.item())

    if t % 5 == 0:
        print("Epoch {}, loss: {:.6f}".format(t, loss.item()), end="\r")
    if t % 50 == 0:
        plt.scatter(train_x.flatten(), train_y.flatten(), label="GT")
        plt.scatter(train_x.flatten(), prediction.detach().flatten(), label="Pred")
        plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12, 8)
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
plt.plot(losses, label="losses")
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12, 8)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This modified code trains fine:
[image]
[image]

But if I set `rescale_data_to_suitable_range = False`, it has the same problem as in your post:

[image]
[image]